# display xml results in ranges

Tags: php, xml

I want to make a pagination like div. Right now div is populated with xml, which displays 6 results. I want on a click of a button to display next/previous 6 results. I have no idea how to force xml return results like from matches[0] to matches[5] and on next click matches[6] to matches[11].

XML in widget.php:

```
foreach ($xml->team->last_matches->match as $match) {
   //some php and html stuff 
}
```

if javascript variable that I pass to file widget.php is `limit`, want something like:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $_GET['limit']; x++)
   foreach ($xml->team->last_matches->match[x] as $match) {
       //some php and html stuff 
    }
}
```

Not sure where to specify to display last six entries up to `limit`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using xpath's node index denoted by square brackets `[]`. Below demonstrates with an example XML of Google Doodles:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1758</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-07-01</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Canada Day 2015</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1759</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-07-04</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Fourth of July 2015</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1760</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-15</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>50th Anniversary of the Canadian Flag</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1761</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-15</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Cricket World Cup 2015 - India vs. Pakistan</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1762</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-17</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Carnival 2015</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1763</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-16</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Rosenmontag 2015</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1764</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-18</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Alessandro Volta's 270th Birthday</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1765</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-24</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Rosalia de Castro's 178th Birthday</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1766</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-19</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Lunar New Year 2015 (Vietnam)</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1767</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-26</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Jose Mauro de Vasconcelos' 95th Birthday</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
    <GoogleDoodles>
        <ID>1768</ID>
        <DoodleDate>2015-02-19</DoodleDate>
        <Doodle>Lunar New Year 2015</Doodle>
    </GoogleDoodles>
</root>
```

**PHP** Script

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/xml/file.xml');
# $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

$limit = 5;

for($j=0; $j <= $limit; $j++) {

    foreach ($xml->xpath("//GoogleDoodles[".$j."]/Doodle") as $d) {
        echo $d->saveXML()."\n";
    }

}    

// <Doodle>Canada Day 2015</Doodle>
// <Doodle>Fourth of July 2015</Doodle>
// <Doodle>50th Anniversary of the Canadian Flag</Doodle>
// <Doodle>Cricket World Cup 2015 - India vs. Pakistan</Doodle>
// <Doodle>Carnival 2015</Doodle>
```